# what is cost more ? sockets or file IO operations?

Tags: c++, sockets, file-io

what is cost more, sending multiple socket messages (let's say 20 messages that contain 5000 characters per message) between 2 processes on the same machine or combines these messages into one message and writes it in a temp file and just sends the file path to the other process?

given that the used language is c++.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark this? Creating small example programs that does just what you describe would be pretty quick and effortless.

Comment: Sockets will be much faster than file IO operations.

Comment: There are also many other ways of [IPC (Inter-Process Communication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: If you want speed, [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) should be better than files. At least it is more predictable.